# Netbeans, can't connect to SQL server

Tags: sql, netbeans, sql-server-2014

[I am trying to connect to a SQL Express 2014 Server but keep getting this error message. I have followed several tutorials and they all lead me to the same point. Can anyone help decipher the error message please?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DjYN.png)

Full error message: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://BatExtractW1:1433/master;instance=SQLEXPRESS using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver (Unable to get information from SQL Server: BatExtractW1.)

Comment: either you didn't enable tcp in mssql, it's not listening on localhost:1433, or there's a firewall dropping the local packets.

Comment: I have checked TCP/IP is enabled and turned off firewall but still no luck

Comment: enabling tcp isn't enough. mssql will only bind to ports/ips you specify, and will happily run with tcp enabled and NO bindings at all.

Comment: Thanks again Marc for your reply. I have turned off dynamic ports in SQL server config manager and set the port to 1433 as my client instructed. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Fixed it, I don't know what the issue was but uninstalling and reinstalling fixed it. Thanks for your help Marc.